# How to bound the norm of this matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $(A_n)$, $(B_n)$, $(C_n)$ be sequences of $n\times k$ matrices, where $k<n$ is fixed and

$$A'_nA_n=B'_nB_n=C'_nC_n=I_k \hspace{1cm} $$

$$A_n'C_n=0$$

$$\|A_n\|_F=\|B_n\|_F=\|C_n\|_F=\sqrt{k}$$

for each $n$.

How can I bound the Frobenius norm of the matrix $A_nA'_nB_nB'_nC_nC'_n$ as $n\to\infty$?

I feel it should be quite small when $n$ is large. But I don't know how to show it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume that the matrices are real and that $A'$ denotes the transpose of $A$. If this is the case and the matrices are $n\times n$, then $A'A = I_n \implies AA' = I_n$, and we have $AA'BB'CC' = I_n$ in all cases.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes sorry I meant $n\times k$ matrices with $k< n$. I corrected the typo.

Comment: Note: the fact that $A'C = 0$ means that we must have $k \leq n/2$

Comment: There is no reason to believe that this norm should be particularly small. As an example, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{I_k \\ 0_{k \times k}}, \quad C = \pmatrix{0_{k \times k}\\ I_k}, \quad B = \frac 1{\sqrt{2k}}\pmatrix{1\\ \vdots \\ 1}.
$$
We end up with $\|AA'BB'CC'\|_F = \frac 12$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Oh right. I must add that the Frobenius norms of $A$,$B$ and $C$ are bounded as $n\to \infty$. Sorry I forgot to add that when translating my problem. We can look at $A_n$,$B_n$,$C_n$ as bounded sequences of $n\times k$ matrices.

Comment: @BenGrossmann To make it simple lets assume that the norm of $A_n,B_n,C_n$ is $1$ for each $n$. See my edit.

Comment: This might be useful: we have 
$$
\|AA'BB'CC'\|_F^2 = 
\operatorname{tr}[AA'BB'(CC')^2BB'AA'] \\ = 
\operatorname{tr}[(AA')^2BB'(CC')^2BB'] = 
\operatorname{tr}[AA'BB'CC'BB']\\
\leq
\|AA'BB'\|_F
\|CC'BB'\|_F
$$
And $\|AA'BB'\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}[AA'BB'] = \|A'B\|_F^2$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Right but how can I exploit the orthogonality of $A_n$ and $C_n$ from there?

Comment: It is impossible for $A_n$ to have bounded Frobenius norm with respect to $n$ if we also have $A_n'A_n = I$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann but $A_n'A_n = I_k$ which does not depend on $n$. $A_n$,$B_n$ and $C_n$ are matrices of normalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Oops you're right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$
\|AA'BB'CC'\|_F^2 =  \operatorname{tr}[AA'BB'(CC')^2BB'AA'] \\ =  \operatorname{tr}[(AA')^2BB'(CC')^2BB'] =  \operatorname{tr}[AA'BB'CC'BB']\\ \leq \|AA'BB'\|_F \|CC'BB'\|_F,
$$
and $\|AA'BB'\|_F^2 = \operatorname{tr}[AA'BB'] = \|A'B\|_F^2$.

With that established, note that the matrix $W = [A \ \ C]$ has orthogonal columns. It follows that
$$
\|B\|_F^2 \geq \|W'B\|_F^2 = \left\|\pmatrix{A'B\\C'B} \right\|_F^2 = \|A'B\|_F^2 + \|C'B\|_F^2.
$$
Now, we note that the maximum
$$
\max_{a,b\geq 0} ab \quad \text{s.t.} \quad a^2 + b^2 = \|B\|_F^2
$$
is attained with $a = b = \|B\|_F/\sqrt{2}$ (as can be seen with the AM-GM inequality for instance). Putting all this together, we have
$$
\|AA'BB'CC'\|_F^2 \leq \|A'B\|_F \cdot \|C'B\|_F \leq \frac 12 \|B\|_F^2 = k/2.
$$

Comment: Right! Can I also say that the spectral norm of $A_nA'_nB_nB'_nC_nC'_n$ converges to zero as $n\to \infty$?

Comment: @Alphie I don't see a way to reach that conclusion

Comment: @Alphie In fact, if we take $B_n = \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}A_n + \frac 1{\sqrt{2}}C_n$, we have
$$
A_nA_n'B_nB_n'C_nC_n' = \frac 12[A_nC_n'] = 
\frac 12 \pmatrix{A_n & C_n} \pmatrix{0&I_k\\0&0}\pmatrix{A_n'\\ C_n'},
$$
and the spectral norm of this matrix does not converge to zero.

Comment: Can you explain why the spectral norm cannot converge to zero in this case?

Comment: Let $x = C_n y$ for any vector $y$ with $\|y\| = 1$. We see that
$$
\|\frac 12 A_nC_n' x\| = \frac 12\| A_n y\| = \frac 12 \|y\| = \frac 12.
$$
So, the spectral norm is at least $1/2$.

Comment: I see. Do you see a way to at least show that the modulus of the largest eigenvalue of $A_nA_n'B_nB_n'C_nC_n' $ converges to zero?

Comment: @Alphie Yes. $[A_nA_n'B_nB_n'C_nC_n']^2 = 0$ for all $n$, which means that $0$ is its only eigenvalue for all $n$.

Comment: Oh yes sorry I missed that. And what about the largest eigenvalue modulus of $B'_nA_nA_n'B_nB_n'C_nC_n'B_n$? Can I bound it by something that converges to zero?

Comment: In fact can I adapt this argument to show that the Frobenius norm of $A_nA_n'B_nB_n'C_nC_n'B_nB'_n$ converges to zero?

Comment: @Alphie I don't see how you would be able to do that